# Pyxll 'ipywidgets.widgets' reloading error

Tags: python, excel, pyxll

I have been having the below error trying to reload Pyxll since updating my Anaconda version to 5.0.1 Python 2.7 64.

```
ERROR : Not reloading dependency ipywidgets.widgets because of previous failure 
to reload ipywidgets.widgets.interaction
2018-07-30 13:57:52,440 - ERROR : Error reloading 
'ipywidgets.widgets.interaction'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to pyxll.cfg config:

```
deep_reload_exclude = 
    ipywidgets
    traitlets
```

Which excludes troublesome modules. Thanks to Pyxll support for soln.